# Is it true that $I \otimes B$ is primitive ideal of $A \otimes B$?

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}-$ algebras and $A \otimes B$ denotes minimal(spatial) tensor product. Let $I$ be primitive ideal of $A$.

> Is it true that $I \otimes B$ is primitive ideal of $A \otimes B$?( I'm mainly interested in the case when B is simple)